# Kml parsing issue in silverlight

Tags: .net

I am trying to parse a kml file to xml to get the coordinates in silverlight.
But it didn't parse in the specific format as root element repeats with each element.
Please suggest any better way as i am newbie to silverlight.

```
OpenFileDialog openDiag = new OpenFileDialog();
if ((bool)openDiag.ShowDialog())
{
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openDiag.File.OpenRead());
  while (!reader.EndOfStream)
  {
     str = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  reader.Close();
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
  IEnumerable<POI> list = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Placemark")
                          select new POI
                          {
                            accountID = MainPage.CurrentAccount,
                            Name = (string)p.Element("name").Value,
                            Lat1 = decimal.Parse((string)p.Element("latitude").Value),
                            Long1 = Parse((string)p.Element("longitude").Value),
                          };
```